# Data did not populate in select option tag in REACTJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to populate response data in `<select> <option>` dynamically.

Example Data:

```
{
   "uuid":"123123",
   "car_manufacturer":"Audi",
   "models":[
      {
         "car_model":"model_name",
         "uuid":"213"
      },
      {
         "car_model":"model_name",
         "uuid":"213"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to map only `models` array in select options.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
 const [model, setModel] = useState([]);

   {model ?
          <>
            { model.models.map((item, i) => (
               <option key={i} value={i} >
               {item.car_model}
               </option>
             ))}
             </> :
             <>
             <div>Loading...</div>
             </>}
```

The Error am getting

```
TypeError: model.map is not a function
```

Comment: first of all model is an object not an array so it should be `useState({})` or sth similar. also, can you `console.log` model to see what it prints?

Comment: console.log displays the Example Data as i mentioned above

Comment: i use useEffect to fetch the response from API and set the state and useState({})  as well still not working

Comment: ok found the problem. posting my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initiate your `model` object as an empty array

```
const [model, setModel] = useState([]);
```

so `model ?` will be true, though it won't find `models` property nor `map` function in an unknown property.

Initialize your `model` as `undefined` or `null` and check also for `models` property in your code

So, I would suggest to do the following changes:

```
const [model, setModel] = useState(null);
```

and

```
{ model && model.models ?
```